# The process cannot access a file because it is being used by another process while doing web deployment

Tags: iis, deployment, msbuild

I am using automatic web deployment from TFS to depoly my build daily. In my web site I have one log file. When deploying I am getting "The process cannot access a file  because it is being used by another process" this error causes deployment to fail.

Can anybody tell me how to force delete of the old while automatic deploying? I have to do IISRESET to deploy.
Thanks
Ashwani

Comment: Are you sure it is the log file that is causing this?

Comment: Yea, I am using Enterprise library for logging in file, and the error is coming for that file only.

Comment: Is the logfile part of your deployment? Or does the deploy try to remove it? Can you put your logfile in a different folder?

Comment: The file is not a part of deployment. Deployment tries to remove the file.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do a full `iisreset /stop` before you attempt your deployment, then after the deployment is successful restart your server with `iisreset /start`.

Alternatively, if you have other Web sites on the same host, try stopping the application pool by itself, deploying, then restarting the app. pool. You can use `appcmd` for this:

- `appcmd list apppool` lists your application pools
- `appcmd stop apppool <name>` stops a pool
- `appcmd start apppool <name>` starts a pool

To do this from MSBuild, try the [extension pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score -1):

If the file you specify for the FlatfileTraceListener is read-only, the trace listener does not write the data to the file and no exception occurs. Make sure that the file attributes are set to read/write.
When you use the FlatFileTraceListener class to write log information to a file, the application block locks the file until the application closes. It is possible to open and read the file but you cannot move or delete the log file until you close the application.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648115.aspx